# How do I bind a function that is used as a angular filter predicate

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm using typescript and angular and I'm having trouble getting a function on my controller to be bound to the this. I should point out that the controller and the $scope are two different things in my case.

I've tried angular.bind(this, this.filterViewedStagingItems); but that didn't work. I can do an inlined function and retain the $scope through a closure, but it's not an elegant way of solving the issue.

Html:

```
<div class="table-entry row table-entry stagingItem" ng-repeat="stagingItem in stagingItems|filter:vm.filterViewedStagingItems">
```

Code:

```
export interface IFooController extends ng.IScope {
    vm: Controller;
    isNewForSupplier:boolean;
    isNewForRestaurant:boolean;
    isPackSizeDescChanged:boolean;
    isDescChanged:boolean;
}

export class Controller{
    public static $inject = [
        '$scope',
        '$rootScope',
        '$routeParams'
    ];

    constructor(private $scope:IFooController,
                $rootScope: ng.IScope,
                private $routeParams:any)
    {
        $scope.vm = this;
        angular.bind(this, this.filterViewedStagingItems);//Doesn't work
    }

    private filterViewedStagingItems(stagingItem: StagingItem): boolean
    {
        if (this.$scope.isNewForRestaurant && stagingItem.isNewForRestaurantOnly())
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.$scope.isNewForSupplier && stagingItem.isNewItemOnly())
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.$scope.isDescChanged && stagingItem.isDescriptionChangedOnly())
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.$scope.isPackSizeDescChanged && stagingItem.isPackSizeChangedOnly())
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.$scope.isPackSizeDescChanged && this.$scope.isDescChanged && stagingItem.isDescriptionOrPackSizeDescChangedOnly())
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.areAnyFiltersEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private areAnyFiltersEnabled():boolean
    {
        return this.$scope.isNewForRestaurant || this.$scope.isNewForSupplier || this.$scope.isDescChanged || this.$scope.isPackSizeDescChanged
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a lambda :

```
private filterViewedStagingItems= (stagingItem: StagingItem): boolean => {
}
```

PS: if unclear about what a lambda does : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Comment: Btw I wouldn't call it private ;)